# List of events triggered on pages matching regex

Tags: google-analytics, filtering, regular-expression

Is there a way to get the grouped list of events (such as in *Top events*) which were triggered on pages matching a regular expression?

I may add the *Page* secondary dimension in *Top events* and apply the regex filter but this way I won't get a grouped list.

I may apply the filter to *Events -> Pages* report but this way the events will be grouped only inside pages whilst I need global grouping.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? What regex are you using and what do you expect to be in your grouped list?

Comment: i use this kind of regex to filter pages by url: `/(ask|demand)/`. i want events to be grouped by category/action/label as in "Top events" report

Comment: ok, wait. Event categories, actions and labels are set up through events, pages are tracked by pageviews (not events). So, you'd like to see events which were triggered on specific pages? If that's the case, you need to set up an "advanced filter" and apply that on your events dashboard.

Comment: @DKOATED, please correct me if i'm wrong: using advanced filter implies that the data will be collected differently after the advanced filter is applied and it is better to create a separate profile for that?

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean filters, but "advanced segments"... these filter your already collected data and outputs the filtered data on your dashboard. it does in no way alter or collect data differently. I'm going to add an answer below in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Use Advanced Segments to set up filtering rules on already collected web stats. Apply your regex here and browse to "Content->Events->Overview", apply your segment and your are basically done ...

[image: Advanced Segments]

Comment: advanced segments operate on visits level (not pageviews) which means i'm gonna get: 1. events 2. which were triggered on all the pages 3. which were visited in the sessions 4. which contained pageviews of urls matching regex. am i right?